# Php 7.0 to 7.2 updates to 7.4

Tags: php, php-7.2, php-7.4, php-7.0

Its kind of weird question, I updated my 7.0 to 7.2 php, but when I checked it with phpinfo its written php 7.4.6.

i used this commands

```
 add-apt-repository ppa: ondrej/php
 apt-get update
 apt-get purge php7.0 php7.0-common
 apt-get install php7.2-curl php7.2-xml php7.2-zip php7.2-gd php7.2-mysql php7.2-mbstring
 init 6
```

Comment: Which web server do you use? Please check your web server configuration. For instance, check _/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*_ for the php version. A system may have multiple version of PHP installed.

Comment: Write `php -v` in the terminal see what that outputs; should be 7.2.x. If so that's been installed correctly. 
Then as @tgram says see what the web server is passing the PHP requests to.

Comment: php -v outputs 7.4.6

Comment: I am using apache web server